# What is the payment transaction state when the buy confirmation popup is visible?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

What is the payment transaction state if there is one when the buy confirmation popup is visible?

Is it suppose to be SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing, I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The enum SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing refers the a transaction being processed by the App Store, not the user being in a state of "purchasing" an in app purchase.

The method where this is relevant

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions

    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
         NSString *productId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

    if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
        [self paymentTransactionFailed:transaction.error.code];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    }    
    and so on for the other enums
```

should be called from

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {   
    if([response.products count] > 0) {
       SKProduct *product = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

       SKPayment *paymentRequest = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:paymentRequest];
    }    
    handling more than one product in the response if necessary
```

which occurs only after the user has either canceled or confirmed the in app purchase.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are saying the callback for the alert is handled in didReceiveResponse?

Comment: So you will get a callback to -(void)productRequest... after the user answers the confirm purchase alert. Afterward you will call the -(void)paymentQueue... (I have made an edit above to make this more clear).